# Who is Crocket?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, spider-man, spider-man-homecoming

In *Spider-Man: Homecoming*, after Peter Parker said that he was going to personally take down the Vulture, Tony Stark says to him,

> "Easy now, Crocket. That is way above your pay grade."

**Who is Crocket?**

Comment: Possibly Davy Crockett (Kind of the wild frontier...)? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Crockett

Comment: this 100% few more letters okay ^^

Answer (score 46, accepted):

Erm, more likely a reference to James "Sonny" Crockett, the rule-breaking  detective of the 1984-1990 [Miami Vice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Miami_Vice) duo of Crockett and Ricardo "Rico" Tubbs.

[image: Tubbs and Crockett]

[Crockett is depicted as a rogue character, that lives by his own set of rules and he is often angered by and in conflict with orders from his superiors, even though he is a highly moral person.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Crockett)

"You've got to know the rules before you can break 'em. Otherwise, it's no fun." -- [Crockett](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0086759/quotes)

Comment: I tried to find a quote of Crockett saying he was going to "personally take down <insert drug dealer who hurt someone Crockett cares about>" and I couldn't find it, but I wouldn't be surprised at all if it's hiding somewhere in a Miami Vice episode. +1

Comment: This qualifies as an outstanding, out of the box, concise, hit the nail on the head answer. Thank you and+1.

Comment: Also, this makes me feel old.

Comment: @ToddWilcox The closest I can get is the more-or-less famous _"I will clear my desk of all my other cases and spend every waking hour making sure you fry for the murder of a cop"_. Great excuse to watch every episode again.